# No Matching Provisioning Profile Found

Tags: ios, icloud, archive, provisioning-profile

I am submitting my first app to apple store and is doing Archive. Then I got this error: `No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier, com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers, com.apple.developer.icloud-services, com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers.`  . I deleted my provisioning files and created again, but didn't work. What should I do? I also put screenshot below for my Code Signing settings and iCloud in Capabilities.

[image]

[image: iCloud]

Comment: it tells you explicitly to add iCloud containers to your App ID, did you do that?

Comment: Hi Mert, I did pick iCloud when creating App ID. Problem is suboptions didn't show up and by default Xcode 5 was selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by choosing the "include CloudKit support (requires Xcode 6)". When I created APP ID, I picked iCloud, but no suboptions for this. This is really not good. It costs me whole morning. I hope it can help someone.

Comment: omg thank you. I've just lost a whole morning trying to fix that too...

Comment: My pleasure can help.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this issue is to delete all Provisioning Profiles and recreate the Distribution profiles from https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/

Set my Code Signing > Release ... to my team
Set my Provisioning Profiles ... all to automatic.

I re-archived and everything works as expected.